# How do I relate a Django model from a related table back to anoher record first model?

Tags: django-models

I have a course catalogue and am trying to include pre-requisits.
A course has 0 to n pre-requisits and a course can be the pre-quesit for 0 to n courses.
The course class is as follows

```
class Course(models.Model):
    class Meta:
    ordering = ['course_code', 'title']    
    course_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    course_code = models.SlugField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False)
    ....
    ....

class Pre_requisit(models.Model)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, course_id')
    pre_req = ???????
```

I have tried the pre_req field as a ForeginKey and MamyToManyField but cant find a solution.
Django will not allow 2 ForeignKeys from Pre_requisit class to the Course class.
With the ManyToMany field evn through another table I still get errors.

Can anyone let me know how to acheive this relationship.
I wish to ensure the pre-requisit course exists and be able to link to it so it can be displayed.

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you read what the errors say? Cause they should tell you that you need to specify a related name :)
Also, please use the `101010` button for your code so it get's highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Course(models.Model):
    ....
    pre_req = models.ManyToManyField("self")
```

read more at http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield

If you wish to store extra info you can specify a "through" table also ( info at http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany) such as hard pre-requisite or recommended etc.

Comment: Hi. This seems to only allow one pre requisit.
Is there a way to have many pre requisits?